# Drop output from a Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks

I have a simple net:

```
net = NetInitialize@
  NetChain[{LinearLayer[2], SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> 2, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]]

net@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}]
```

How do I return probabilites after `SoftmaxLayer`? Right now I have to insert dummy `ElementwiseLayer[Identity]` in the end of a chain and then `Take[net,2]` would return what I actually need.

Comment: The "Class" NetDecoder page shows how to obtain the probabilities as a Basic Example: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/netdecoder/Class.html

Comment: `net[#, "Probabilities"][[All, Key[1]]]&` works for me

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this:

```
num=RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
net[num,"Probabilities"]
```

[image]

And there is a new function `NetDrop` in 11.3.0, you can check:

```
SoftmaxLayer["Input" -> 2]@NetDrop[net, -1][num]
```

[image]

Exactly the same.